# How to count values that match a certain condition when another condition is met?

Tags: bash

I have a csv file with 10 columns. I need to sum the number of lines from columns 4 and 5 only where the 3rd column has the value `"CODE"`
I need to use bash script.
For example:

```
       3rd col, 4th col, 5th col
Line 1: DECODE     23       12
Line 2: CODE       10       20

Output: 10 + 20 = 30
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, on SO it's highly encouraged for users to do add their efforts in form of code, do kindly do add the same in your question and let us know then.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) with correct field separator and your desired output (no descriptions, no images, no links) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 1):

AWK to the rescue:

```
$ cat foo.csv                         
1st col, 2nd col, 3rd col, 4th col, 5th col
1,1,DECODE,23,12
2,2,CODE,10,20

$ cat run.sh
#!/bin/bash  
awk -F "," '{ if ($3 == "CODE") print $4 + $5 }' foo.csv

$ sh run.sh 
30
```

Comment: When running the script I get no response. Here is my script;                                
`#!/bin/bash

awk -F "," '{ if ($3 == "CODE") print $4 + $5 }' <CODE.csv>
`

Comment: @NickTsoros Remove the <> surrounding the name of the file

Comment: Still the same output

Comment: @NickTsoros I updated my answer with more details. Please let me know if you're still having issues.

Comment: Worked by the addition of ; after if parenthesis``awk -F "," '{ if ($3 == "CODE"); print $4 + $5 }``   . However the output is not one number but a list of additions