# Reading a csv file to count the number of sub users based on the access method in java

Tags: java, arrays, file

**I am currently reading a csv file with the following code:**

- This is just reading a file code.
- I have read the file and I am getting the file data as output.

**What i want to achieve: **
Please click the link to check the sample data.
**
**[Sample Data]: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXMAo.png)****

```
package testing;
import java.io.*;
`public class GarExcel` {

    public static final String delimiter = ",";
    public static void read(String csvFile) {

        try {
            File file = new File(csvFile);
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String line = "";
            String[] tempArr;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                // use as comma seperator
                tempArr = line.split(delimiter);
                for (String tempStr: tempArr) {

                    System.out.print(tempStr + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

           String csvFile = "C:/Users/John.Cena/Documents/ExcelTesting/gar-20230901.csv";
           GarExcel.read(csvFile);
    }
}
```

I want to count the number of sub users based on the access method.

So for eg if you refer to the image/ image link I want the output to have the count of sub user JL and same for TW2JL. So as per the image I want the output to be:

```
Count of JL - 11
Count of TW2JL - 15.
```

Now the thing is the csv file is more than 2GB and has more than 2 million records. It will have more than 200 sub users. And I want to count the number of all sub users based on the access method.
I have attached a screenshot as well above with a tag sample data that will help you guys understand my question.
I am new to java and your suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest to do that task with basic *nix shell programs, or maybe a custom shellscript. I think it will be way faster than doing that in java. maybe this helps by doing so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64085303/how-to-count-values-that-match-a-certain-condition-when-another-condition-is-met

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Java 8 or higher, read the file content into a stream using `Files.lines` map each line to the sub-user column, group by sub-user using `Function.identity()` and the counting collector. The result map should have then the desired content of sub groups mapped to their frequency. Example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Example {

    public static final String delimiter = ",";
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {

        String csvFile = "/path/to/your/csv/test.csv";

        Stream<String> fileContent = readFile(csvFile);
        Map<String, Long> subUserCount = groupBySubUser(fileContent);

        subUserCount.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println(k + " : " + v));
    }

    private static Stream<String> readFile(String csvFile) throws IOException {
        return Files.lines(Path.of(csvFile));
    }

    private static Map<String, Long> groupBySubUser(final Stream<String> fileContent) {
        return fileContent.skip(1) //skip header
                          .map(line -> line.split(delimiter)[2]) //map each line to 3rd column
                          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.counting()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do we need ‘LinkedHashmap’,we just need the count